# C# webservice adding extra node

Tags: c#, json, visual-studio, web-services, wcf

I am writing an c# service to generate questions and answers. My code for the service is as follows

```
public interface IExamService
{
    [OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(Method = "GET",UriTemplate = "/ExamQs",RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped)]
    string GetExam();
}

public string GetExam()
{
    List<ExamClass> exam = new List<ExamClass>();
    for(int i=0; i < 4; i++)
    {
        ExamClass ex = new ExamClass();
        ex.Question = "This is the Question no "+ i.ToString();
        ex.Answer1 = "This is Answer1 of Question " + i.ToString();
        ex.Answer2 = "This is Answer2 of Question " + i.ToString();
        ex.Answer3 = "This is Answer3 of Question " + i.ToString();
        ex.Answer4 = "This is Answer4 of Question " + i.ToString();
        ex.Correct = 1;
        exam.Add(ex);
    }

    string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(exam);
    return json;
}
```

This is the Exam class i am using to get the questions from the database. For now I am hard coding the Exam class.

```
namespace ExamService
{
public class ExamClass
{
    string question;
    string answer1;
    string answer2;
    string answer3;
    string answer4;
    Int32 correct;

    public string Question
    {
        get
        {
            return question;
        }

        set
        {
            question = value;
        }
    }

    public string Answer1
    {
        get
        {
            return answer1;
        }

        set
        {
            answer1 = value;
        }
    }

    public string Answer2
    {
        get
        {
            return answer2;
        }

        set
        {
            answer2 = value;
        }
    }

    public string Answer3
    {
        get
        {
            return answer3;
        }

        set
        {
            answer3 = value;
        }
    }

    public string Answer4
    {
        get
        {
            return answer4;
        }

        set
        {
            answer4 = value;
        }
    }

    public int Correct
    {
        get
        {
            return correct;
        }

        set
        {
            correct = value;
        }
    }
}
```

}

The output is

```
{"GetExamResult":"[{\"Question\":\"This is the Question no 0\",\"Answer1\":\"This is Answer1 of Question 0\",\"Answer2\":\"This is Answer2 of Question 0\",\"Answer3\":\"This is Answer3 of Question 0\",\"Answer4\":\"This is Answer4 of Question 0\",\"Correct\":1},{\"Question\":\"This is the Question no 1\",\"Answer1\":\"This is Answer1 of Question 1\",\"Answer2\":\"This is Answer2 of Question 1\",\"Answer3\":\"This is Answer3 of Question 1\",\"Answer4\":\"This is Answer4 of Question 1\",\"Correct\":1},{\"Question\":\"This is the Question no 2\",\"Answer1\":\"This is Answer1 of Question 2\",\"Answer2\":\"This is Answer2 of Question 2\",\"Answer3\":\"This is Answer3 of Question 2\",\"Answer4\":\"This is Answer4 of Question 2\",\"Correct\":1},{\"Question\":\"This is the Question no 3\",\"Answer1\":\"This is Answer1 of Question 3\",\"Answer2\":\"This is Answer2 of Question 3\",\"Answer3\":\"This is Answer3 of Question 3\",\"Answer4\":\"This is Answer4 of Question 3\",\"Correct\":1},{\"Question\":\"This is the Question no 4\",\"Answer1\":\"This is Answer1 of Question 4\",\"Answer2\":\"This is Answer2 of Question 4\",\"Answer3\":\"This is Answer3 of Question 4\",\"Answer4\":\"This is Answer4 of Question 4\",\"Correct\":1}]"}
```

my question is why c# is adding 'GetExamResult' at the start and how to get rid of it. Thanks.

Comment: Please post `ExamClass`

Answer (score 3):

> why c# is adding 'GetExamResult' at the start and how to get rid of it

This is due to `BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped`. When the `BodyStyle` is wrapped, the serializer wraps the response in an extra JSON (or XML) level (see [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.web.webmessagebodystyle(v=vs.110).aspx)).

I know that this can be cumbersome and is not always wanted, but there are situations, in which a `Wrapped` body is desired or required. This is the case when you are returning bare values (as an `int` or a `string`), since you can't map simple values to JSON. Actually this is the case with your code. With the `ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json` you are not teilling the runtime that you intend to return a JSON `string`, but rather you are telling the runtime to convert your return value to a valid JSON. Ans since a `string` is not valid JSON, it's needed to be wrapped in a JSON.

Anyway, there is a very simple way for you to achieve what you want (and it even makes your code a bit easier). Just make your web method directly return an `ExamClass` instance. All you have to do is annotating the `ExamClass` class (*side note*: please don't suffix your class names with `Class` - this is bad style) with the `DataContractAttribute` and its members with the `DataMemberAttribute`

```
[DataContract]
public class ExamClass
{
    string question;
    string answer1;
    string answer2;
    string answer3;
    string answer4;
    Int32 correct;

    [DataMember]
    public string Question
    {
        get
        {
            return question;
        }

        set
        {
            question = value;
        }
    }

    [DataMember]
    public string Answer1
    {
        get
        {
            return answer1;
        }

        set
        {
            answer1 = value;
        }
    }

    // ...
}
```

and then you can return an object of `ExamClass` directly from `IExamService`

```
public interface IExamService
{
    [OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(Method = "GET",
        UriTemplate = "/ExamQs",
        RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
        ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
        BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare)]
    ExamClass GetExam();
}
```

This is a bit more how WPF is intended to be used.